# How can I monitorize the buffer of an embedded YouTube video on Android?

Tags: android, video, youtube, buffer, monitoring

First of all, sorry for my poor English.

I am developing an application to monitor and get statistics on youtube videos played. I have developed an application on Android withit an embedded Youtube video player and I want to get all events that happen during the video is playing. I know how to get some events such as when it has been stopped, when it is buffering or when it stops buffering.

The problem is that it would be very interesting for me to get some statistics about the bytes that are loaded in the buffer everytime I check it but I don't know how to do that. I have checked the youtube player API and I know that it is possible when you use Javascript but the API that they offer for Android doesn´t have this option.

Please do you have any idea about how I can monitorize the buffer during a video is playing?

Thank you!

Comment: Well if you want to do it in realtime (display the bytes that have just been read), that's hard to execute. However, I believe that you can add a couple of lines in your buffering method that concurrently write to a text file vie FileOutputStream for example, and afterwards look at the contents of the text file. That way the bytes would be written in order they are obtained (decoded) although you won't get the exact time of the execution. Here's documentation page for the FileOutputStream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean but I think that your method is only a way to store all the bytes of the video in a text.

Comment: But I need an statistic about how many bytes are loaded in the buffer at the moment that I check it to get after a graphic with the evolution of the bytes loaded during the video is playing.

Comment: Well I can't help you with that :( My only idea is to have a timer running on a separate thread. Timer interval is 1000ms (1 sec) and whenever timer ticks you reset your counter variable. Independently, in your byte stream cycle you increment the variable by one whenever you read a block of bytes (I assume they are read in 1024-byte blocks) . Then when you check for information, display the last known value of your counter variable multiplied by byte block size. This could give you the info about the bytes read in the previous second.